# text moves to different div: css

Tags: html, css

Here is the plunkr:

The issue is for this div

https://plnkr.co/edit/HHsReAT6GLyNZTF4qOJj?p=preview

```
<div class="main-page">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 welcome-text">Ankur Chavda</div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 intro">Programmer, Singer Song-Writer, Football</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can see the css classes in plunkr.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: From your plunkr, if you remove "line-height: 100vh;", from ".main-page"  in the CSS, you will see the text in the two divs next to each other. Is this how you wanted to show the content ?

Comment: @ami91 Yes, but I also want them to be in the center, how can I get that?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the line height from:

```
.main-page {
    background-color: #293b4d;
    width: 100%;
    height: 90vh;
    /* text-align: center; */
    /* vertical-align: middle; */
}
```

if you really want those two div elemnts to centered be to the main-page you can try this:

```
.main-page{
    background-color: #293b4d;
    width: 100%;
    height: 90vh;
    /* text-align: center; */
    /* vertical-align: middle; */
    position:relative;
}
.holder {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

And then add another div element with class named "holder" as a parent of the row like this:

```
<div class='holder'>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6 welcome-text">Ankur Chavda</div>
      <div class="col-xs-4 intro">Programmer, Singer Song-Writer, Football</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope that will work.

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: It is working without any problem. I just did the same what I had instructed before. Please check back. I have replicated the same thing on my JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/evanshajed/8nnj9cf4/

Comment: It did. Thanks. I made some mistake in copy pasting your code.

Comment: Your solution adds extra space to the right. You can check the plunkr and verify.

Comment: Just Checked. Can you please be more specific? That may happen because of the vertical centering approach that has been taken.

You can have a look at this link to check different centering trick and choose what is best for you: https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/